# Python context for file or None

Tags: python, file-handling, with-statement

Python is going to call a subprocess, the user either requested that subprocesses stdout is to go to a file (or back-holed to os.devnull), or the subprocesses output is to be passed though "in real time".

My current best guess as how to do this would seemingly work:

- Let `file_path` be valid input for `open()`
- Let `logging` be a Boolean indicator, true indicating use `file_path` for logging or false to passthough to stdout.

---

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') if logging else None as shell_stdout:
    subprocess.call(['ls'], stdout=shell_stdout)
```

In tinkering/testing this appears to be the right value, which I have assumed work well with subprocess.call. However, and unsurprisingly I get the following exception:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

So `None` is not a context, it has no `__exit__`;

---

#### Goals

- Not open a file at all if the user does not want logging.
- Use contexts (as provided by the stdlib), (Preference; I can't imagine doing the file open/close operations manually being any cleaner.)
- Not need a try/catch (Preference to avoid further nesting)
- Only have a single call to `subprocesses.call` (Non duplicated line)

So, how could this behavior be achieved? Or what would you suggest doing instead/alternatively?

Comment: I'd suggest dropping the 4th goal and just using two different `subprocess.call`, given the additional constraint you left as a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a "no-op" [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
import subprocess
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def noop():
    yield None

logging = False
file_path = '/tmp/out'

with open(file_path, 'wb') if logging else noop() as shell_stdout:
    subprocess.call(['ls'], stdout=shell_stdout)
```

When logging is `True`, the conditional expression returns a file object. When `logging` is False, it returns a `noop()` context manager (so it can be used in the `with-statement`), which sets `shell_out` to `None` but doesn't do anything special upon exit.

---

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), when `stdout=None`,

> ... no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

Usually the parent's stdout would equal `sys.stdout`. However, it is possible to redirect `sys.stdout` somewhere else, either explicitly (e.g. `sys.stdout = open('/tmp/stdout', 'wb')`) or indirectly, such as by using module that redirects `sys.stdout`. The `fileinput` module from the standard library redirects `sys.stdout`, for example. In such cases `noop()` might be useful for directing stdout to the parent's stdout, which may be different than `sys.stdout`.

If this corner case does not affect you, then [Padraic Cunningham's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28680680/190597) is simpler:

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') if logging else sys.stdout as shell_stdout:
    subprocess.call(['ls'], stdout=shell_stdout)
```

Answer (score 3):

Either set `shell_stdout` to `stdout` or a `file object` based on logging being True or False, there is no need to overcomplicate it, you only have one condition or the other `if logging` will either be True or False, there is nothing wrong with opening a file not using `with`, there are times when using `with` does not fit.

```
import sys

if logging:
      shell_stdout = open(file_path, 'wb') # to file or devnull if logging
else:
    shell_stdout = sys.stdout
subprocess.call(['ls'], stdout=shell_stdout) # real time if not logging
shell_stdout.close()
```

To do what you wanted in your question you can do the following, you don't need anything bar `sys.stdout`:

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') if logging else sys.stdout as shell_stdout:
    subprocess.call(['ls'], stdout=shell_stdout)
```

The file will only be created if logging is True.

Comment: Note that this will redirect the stdout to the subprocesss PIPE, which you might or might not want.

Comment: @NickBailey I think I can equally substitute `None` for `sys.stdout`, which I think tells Sub processes to do more or less the same thing anyway

Comment: @ThorSummonerm yes that is the point, you can direct it wherever you want. But avoid None as you cannot close None

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.3, tou can define a no-op context manager using [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with open(...) if ... else ExitStack():
    ...
```